# How do you push and commit to git directly from VS code

Tags: git

Having gitbash installed I think it should be possible to commit from VS codes interface

Answer (score 1):

If you launch VSCode while git is in your PATH (%PATH% on Windows, $PATH onLinux/Mac), then the [Version Control feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol) will be active, and you will be able to commit/push when working in a folder with a `.git/` subfolder inside (one created by `git clone`, or initialized with `git init`)

I like adding [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens#:%7E:text=GitLens%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,and%20why%20the%20code%20evolved.) for more git-related features, making the push even easier.